# Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, x12

I am trying to use the x12 package in R. I have installed the x12 from Census in my computer.
After run the following code:

```
library(x12)
x12path("C:/Program Files (x86)/WinX12/x12a/x12a.exe")
xts <- x12(AirPassengers)
```

I have the following error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WinX12\x12a\x12a.exe Rout -g gra_Rout' had status 127 
2: In file(con, "r") :
cannot open file 'Rout.err': No such file or directory
```